# Entering a formula and stop a (number) string loosing the first 0

Tags: vba, excel

Hard to explain.

I am aiming to write into a cell the following formula: `=FDS(0056650,"FG_Price(02/14/2017)")`

The formula works with a COM Add-in and returns a value. The number sequence and date are variables. When I enter this it will default the 0056650 to 556650 even though the string is 0056650.

Code below, j = " Sedol_check is a string.

```
WS_Detailed.Cells(CPA_Row_Count, CPA_Column_Count).Offset(1, 0)_
= "=FDS(" & Sedol_Check & "," & j & "FG_Price(02/14/2017)" & j & ")"
```

The COM add in won't work if the cell is formatted as text. Any ideas welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that `.NumberFormat = "0000000"` wont work in your situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the FDS function needs two string arguments (I'm guessing it's from the FactSet market tracker?), then just enclose the first argument in quotes; change your code to:

```
WS_Detailed.Cells(CPA_Row_Count, CPA_Column_Count).Offset(1, 0)_
= "=FDS(" & j & Sedol_Check & j & "," & j & "FG_Price(02/14/2017)" & j & ")"
```

You can also insert the quotes when you're building Sedol_Check.